# Dropdownlist values comes null on button click.Dropdownlist is placed at first row of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is code that i used to access dropdownlist inside gridview on button click.I know its due to postback of page.But how to fix it.

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GridViewRow row;
row = dgData.Rows[0];
DropDownList ddl= (DropDownList)(row.Cells[1].FindControl("ddlCol1"));

}
```

On page load i have called the method to bind gridview.

```
  if (page.ispostback==false)
 {
grdbind();
  }
```

Comment: is the button inside gridview?

Comment: no its outside...........

Comment: you need to do Postback with any control inside gridview so gridview information will be send back.

Answer (score 0):

try with 0th cell if it is first

```
(row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlCol1"))
```

Comment: it still null.its due to postback.because i have bind dropdown in rowdatabound